# Proving a set is not a embedded submaifold.

Tags: differential-topology

So I am asked to find out which level sets of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=x^3+xy+y^3+1$ are embedded submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

You can see that the points in the set $X=\mathbb{R}-\{1,\frac{28}{27}\}$ are regular values ($(0,0)$ and $(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3})$ are not regular points).

So $f^{-1}(q)$ is a embedded submanifold for every $q$ in $X$.

My question is, how can I find out if $f^{-1}(1)$ is/is not an embedded submanifold? Likewise with $\frac{28}{27}$.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: My bad... its a typo though. My mind was someplace else when I was writting, evidently. Thanks